# conditional classes drupal 7 and IE9

Tags: php, html, css

I wish to use a conditional class to detect if IE9 is being used and apply css accordingly to the class navigation if it is.

I have added the following lineto the html.tpl.php file

`<!--[if IE 9]><html <?php print $html_attributes; ?> class="ie9nav"><![endif]-->`

In the stylsheet.css file, the current class is (which works).

`#navigation {background-image: blah.jpg}`

I added

`#navigation .ie9nav {background-color: fff;}`

but it doesn't work.  What have I done wrong?

Comment: Do you realize that you're adding the class `ie9nav` to your `<html>` tag, which is probably not nested within `#navigation` as your CSS expects?

Comment: argh ok, I'm guessing it should be added to the <body> tag?  If so could you tell me the correct syntax please?

Comment: Nope, it shouldn't. Your CSS rule says "make the background white for any element with class `ie9nav` within the element with ID `navigation`". So basically, you need to have a `<div>` with ID `navigation` somewhere which contains maybe a `ul` or something with the class `ie9nav`. Or you just change the CSS to what you actually want to have. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you directly try it with php itself..

Here is the code snippet which will get handy..

```
if(preg_match('/MSIE/i',$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']))
{
    echo '<html class="ieclass">';
}
else
{
    echo '<html class="none-ie">;
}
```

Hope it helps..

Comment: Thank you but to be honest I'm not at all familiar with writing code in php. Therefore unsure how to go about manipulating that.

Comment: Hmmm.. There are some globals which will help you to get information about the user. I've used one, `$_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']`.. This will be useful when you need to put different things according to the browser of the user..

Comment: Not as tired or have a clearer head this evening. Going to try adding this code. Should this code go within the html.tpl.php file , but where?

Comment: Yes... This code should go into the file where you want to apply css.. Just add it into top of the file and it will check for the user agent first and then apply the class accordingly...